# Escape hyphen in javascript variable

Tags: javascript

The content of variable originalText= "Pending - Submitted for Initial Review"; However when I hover over the div, the tooltip text is truncated after hypen. I have tried escaping the hypen but it's not letting me do it. It always shows the truncated text.

```
$('#study_header').append('<img  src="images/Infow.png" class="tooltip" title=' + originalText + '/>');
```

If anyone knows the solution pls let me know.

After hovering it shows up as below in the source code of the browser:

```
<img src="images/Infow.png" class="tooltip" title="&nbsp;&nbsp;Pending" -="" submitted="" for="" initial="" review ="">
```

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is in your question. Just compare the `title` attribute and its value with the other attributes in the `<img>` tag/string. The safest solution would be to use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do I need to compare the attributes..value of title is coming from variable

Comment: `class="tooltip"` but `title=Pending - Submitted for Initial Review` - What's missing in the `title` attribute? (But seriously... Don't add the attribute with string concatenation. Use specialized tools like `.attr()` that produce valid markup for you)

Comment: I'm not doing string concatenation.. value of the variable is coming from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotation marks around the value of the `title` attribute. You can see it's treating the words in `originalText` as additional attributes.

You can *sort of* fix the problem by changing:

```
'...title=' + originalText + '/>'
```

to (note the added `"` marks):

```
'...title="' + originalText + '"/>'
```

I say this will "sort of" fix it, because if `originalText` contains certain characters (like `"`) this will break again, so you really should be escaping `originalText`. jQuery provides methods for this.

In general you don't want to build HTML with simple string concatenation, because you'll run into escaping issues like this.